# Angular Jasmine Unit Testing: error [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm to setup standalone jasmine testing. I believe I have everything setup correctly. When I run my first test:

```js
describe('Logon Controller', function() {
    var controller, $scope;

    beforeEach(module("app"));

    //beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    //    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    //    contoller = $controller('logonCtrl', {
    //        $scope: scope
    //    });
    //}));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) { 
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    //it('should say hello', function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    //    //var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    //    var controller = $controller('logonCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
    //    //expect(angular.isFunction(scope.get)).toEqual("Hello There :)");
    //    expect(scope.Hello()).toEqual("Hello There :)");
    //    expect($scope.Hello).toBeDefined();
    //});

    it('should say hello', inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        //var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var controller = $controller('logonCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
        //expect(angular.isFunction(scope.get)).toEqual("Hello There :)");
        //expect(scope.Hello()).toEqual("Hello There :)");
        expect($scope.Hello).toBeDefined();
    }));

});
```

I get this error message: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=app.............

Here is my app module config.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngMaterial']);
```

Here is my controller:

```js
app.controller('logonCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$interval', function ($scope, $state, $interval) {
  $scope.hello = function() {};
});
]);
```

I am using the standalone version of Jasmine 2.2.0. I have no clue what the issue could be, everything I have done is pretty basic stuff. Any help would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE: here is what my SpecRunner.html looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.2.0</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/boot.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JasmineUnitTest/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/logonCtrl.js"></script>      

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JasmineUnitTest/specs/logonController-spec.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The part   `beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) { 
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));` should have `$scope` not `scope`. Is it a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo, I was under the assumption that a you could create a variable that holds a new instance of $rootScope, I didn't the name of the variable would make a difference. I'll give that a shot and I'll you know it that helps. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :( and it was a typo, I noticed that I did declared that variable as "$scope" lol.

Comment: Click the debug button on the jasmine browser window. once a new window opens do f12 and check the source tab. Are all the script files loaded correctly?

Comment: I would define 'controller' inside the beforeEach function and instantiate same there (just thinking you'd want to add more tests in the future?), that way your it statement does not have to instantiate the ctrl each time. Also just noticed controller should be a function in your test.

Comment: @Chandermani I don't see a debug button in the jasmine browser window or are you referring to the dev browser tools?

Comment: @Jax700303 I agree with your advice and I had it define there at one point and I was getting the same error. The way I'm doing it now, I found that method when I had done some googleing. Thank you for your advice though.

Comment: I checked my browser dev tools (firebug) and I am getting a network error:    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:62803/js/controllers/logonCtrl.js"                                                     Does this mean Jasmine cannot locate my controller js file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `$injector` fails to find some of your dependencies. Are you sure the script containing your controller is properly loaded ?

Comment: That's what I'm a bit concerned about.  how can you tell if a controller is properly loaded. When deploying the app don't have any issues, at none that I have come across.

Comment: It's probably the js file that is not properly loaded in the tests. Is your controller in a separate file ?

Comment: Yes my controller is in a separate file. In the console for the browser dev tools (firebug) it cannot find my controller js file. I have no idea why though.

Comment: Check the jasmine documentation about how to properly load the controller file. This will fix your problem. :)